# Hide item if not correct user using PassportJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I'm trying to figure out how to hide certain things depending on current username.

I'm trying to hide a button if the user is not the person who created the post. The issue is I need to do this outside of a loop. I only need the button once. If the user is the user who created the post How can I go about showing an object on the page that only that user sees

My code below works I just need it to not be inside of a loop. Any ideas?

```
<% menu.forEach(function(menu){ %>

                 <p>
                   <% if(currentUser && menu.author.id.equals(currentUser._id)){ %>
                    <a href="/menu/<%= menu.id %>" class = "btn btn-primary" > Edit</a>
                    <% } %>
                </p>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it simply using return. Not sure that's the best way to do it but it works:

```
  <% menu.forEach(function(menu){ %>
           <% if(currentUser && menu.author.id.equals(currentUser._id)){ %>
        <div> <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" href="menu/new"> Add an item to your menu </a> </div>


  <% return %>
     <% }%>
     <% }); %>
```